# Why is the function called? JavaScript / Window

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in my HTML file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.never = function() {
                 console.log('this function is never called');
        }
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, srjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "this.script.does.not.exist.js";
            srjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, srjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'streamrail-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sebvaeja/

Looking at the console, you can see that `window.never` function is actually called ('this function is never called' is written to the console).

When debugging this with Chrome dev tools, I see in the call stack that the caller was the closure (first line: `http://jsfiddle.net/sebvaeja/`).

If I change the never function to be off the global scope:

```
    function never() {
             console.log('this function is never called');
    }
```

Then it is not being called.

Can someone please explain why is window.never function being called? What is triggering the call? I guess it's got something to do with the function being on the window object, but I can't see the reasoning behind that.

Comment: Simply put, you have a syntax error. :)

Comment: Also this is a duplicate but I can't find it.

Comment: `var log = function(){ console.log('this function is called'); }(42)`

Comment: What have you learned about relying on automatic semicolon insertion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function expression is followed by parenthesis:

```
 window.never = function() { ... }
 (...)
```

The line break after the function expression does *not* terminate the variable statement, so for the parser that's a function call:

```
function() { ... }(...)
```

In fact, you are using the very same technique here:

```
(function(d, s, id){
  // ...
}(document, 'script', 'streamrail-jssdk'))
```

That's a function expression followed by `(...)` and it calls the function.

**Solution:** Add a semicolon after the definition and you are good.

---

> If I change the never function to be off the global scope ... Then it is not being called.

In that case the function definition is interpreted as function **declaration**, not expression. A function declaration is more like a statement and therefore cannot be part of a *CallExpression*. The following parenthesis are therefore interpreted as grouping operator (like you intended).

Answer (score 5):

Place the semi-colon after the function declaration:

```
    window.never = function() {
             console.log('this function is never called');
    };
```

It's because of the `(...)` directly afterwards that triggers the function call.

```
    window.never = function() {
             console.log('this function is never called');
    }
    ( ... ) // <-- Triggers call of `window.never`
```